# What is it called when an assignment contains conditionals that fall through to be assigned as the value of the variable?

Tags: assignment-operator

I know that this is simple terminology, but I can't get it via google searching...  what is it called when the value of a variable being assigned passes through?

An example in php:

```
<?php 
if($bob = 5){ echo 'The assignment came through as a truthy value!, bob now equals '.$bob.'!'; } 
if($bob = false){ echo 'The assignment occurred again, but the value of the assignment is the value "false", so this if block will not be executed!. Bob now equals '.$bob.'!'; } 
echo ' Finally, bob is a: '.(string) $bob; 
?>
```

An example in javascript:

```
bob = bob || {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you're using assignment as an *expression*; that is, the assignment statement returns the value assigned (this behavior is a common source of bugs; often people accidentally use `=` instead of `==` in their condition).

The second example is using the *short-circuiting* behavior of the `||` operator.

Comment: Assignment as an expression, I can use that,